# Unpack a splitn into a tuple in Rust?

Tags: split, rust, tuples

I want to do the following in Rust:

```
let (command, options) = message.splitn(2, ' ');
```

This can't be done because of:

```
expected struct `std::str::SplitN`, found tuple
```

The split will always be two and I like having named variables.
The message may not contain a space character.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `splitn()` method returns an *iterator* over the parts, so the only way to access them is to actually iterate over them. If you know that there always will be two parts, you can do this:

```
let mut iter = message.splitn(2, ' ');
let command = iter.next().unwrap();
let options = iter.next().unwrap();
```

This will work fine as long as `message` contains at least one space character. For a message without a space, this will panic on the last line, since the iterator is already terminated, so you would call `unwrap()` on `None`. (Note that you need 2 as the first argument to `splitn()` if you want to get two items.)

Starting from Rust 1.52, you can use the `split_once()` method:

```
if let Some((command, options)) = message.split_once(' ') {
    // handle command, options
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, another option is to use `str::split_at()` together with `str::find()`:

```
let (command, options) = message.split_at(message.find(' ').unwrap());
```

Note that the space character will be included in `options` with this solution, whereas the other approaches don't include it.

Comment: I think [`str::split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at) with [`Iterator::position`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) might also be handy

Comment: @Kitsu Nice idea! You would need to use `str::find()` instead of `Iterator::position`, since you need the byte offset rather than the character index, but I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Since Rust 1.52 there is [`str::split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split_once), which returns an Option of a tuple.

Comment: @JannisFroese Thanks, I included this in the answer.