# How to read two named inegers as a tuple in native Rust?

Tags: rust

In Python I can do this:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split(" "))
```

... to get exactly 2 integers from user input.

How can I achive the exact same result in Rust (get 2 integers as a named tuple) without any extern crates?

Comment: Related: [Unpack a splitn into a tuple in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257213/unpack-a-splitn-into-a-tuple-in-rust/62257319#comment129748793_62257319)

Comment: It's unclear what your specific problem is. What have you tried? Which obstacles did you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpack a splitn into a tuple in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257213/unpack-a-splitn-into-a-tuple-in-rust)

Comment: @PitaJ I don't think that's an exact duplicate, because it doesn't convert the results to integers. It's not clear what step the OP has problems with – it might just as well be the integer conversion. Without further information, we don't know.

Comment: Is your question how do I translate the python `a,b = 5,7` into rust?

Answer (score 1):

For the sheer fun of it, I translated your code as literally as possible to Rust:

```
// replace with some read from stdin
let input = "1 2";
let (a, b) = if let &[a, b] = &input.split(' ').map(|c| c.parse::<u32>().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()[..] {
    (a, b)
} else {
    panic!("ValueError: too many/few values to unpack (expected 2)");
};

println!("a = {}, b = {}", a, b);
```

Comment: To replace "as literally as possible", `input` should probably be populated with `io::stdin().read_line()` and `trim()`med.